# How can I make switching between arithmetics easy in C++?

Tags: c++, math

I am making a project that will use mathematic computations a lot. Also I want to be able to simply change the implementation of real numbers. Let's say between float, double, my own implementation and gmplib float types.

So far I thouht of two ways:

1. I create a class "Number" which will interface with the rest of the program.
2. I typedef the arithmetic type and write global functions to interface with the rest of the program.

The first choice seems to be more elegant, but the second seems to have less overhead. Is there a third better choice? Also I am worried by the elementary mathematical functions such as sine, cosine, exp... I figured out that to make the switching easy, I should implement them as templates, but my implementations are hopelessly slow.

I am generally new to programming in C++. I was brought up in the comfortable Matlab and Mathematica environments, where I did not have to worry about such things.

Comment: For my money, templates sound like a pretty natural fit.

Comment: Templates ! You'll be able to define functions without knowing in advance the types involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are the way I have done this. it makes it easy to specialize what must be specialized, and provides a good way to reuse implementations when it applies to multiple types.

The number type can be done, but it's actually not simple to do right and introduces some restrictions (compared to templates).

Multiple types are just hopelessly complex, if you want something even close to fast, accurate, and simple to maintain. You'd likely end up using templates to implement these correctly if you were to create a global `typedef`.

Templates provide all the power, control, and flexibility you would need, and they will be faster than the alternatives posted (technically, #2 could be as fast if you resorted to... templates).

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use templates with constraints to avoid re-implementing things.

For instance, say you want to use `sin` in your program differently for `float` and `double`. You can overload based on type and create specialized templates.

```
template<class T> T MySin(const T& f) {
    return genericSin(f);
}

template<> float MySin<float>(float f) {
    return sinf(f);
}

template<> double MySin<double>(double d) {
    return sin(d);
}
```

For functions. The syntax is similar when partially specializing a `Math` class if you want to go the OO route. This will enable you to call your routines with any type and have the most specialized and most efficient routine called.

Comment: +1 for good advice and a nice clear example.  It's worth pointing out that this works with either the Number type or the typedef, and doesn't address that part of the question.  I suggest `MySin(const T& f)` as some of the `T` values may be large objects.

Answer (score 1):

a template class like real numbers should work for you. in that you can overload the required functions and if required use template specializations.

in order to improve efficiency use STL algorithms instead of hand written loops.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Both alternatives are equivalent in terms of encapsulation: There will be a single point in your program where you'll have to change the number type, and this one change will affect your whole program. If presented with those two alternatives, choose the typedef; it is less elegant (=> simpler, and simpler is better) and has the same power.

When you get more comfortable with C++, templating your functions will be a better fit, since the determination of the number type can be made locally instead of globally. With templates, you determine the number type at the instantiation point (most likely the call site), giving much greater flexibility. However, there is a number of pitfalls in templates, and I'd recommend to you that you get a little more experience with C++ first and then start templating.